# Prevent form submit on enter with Meteor

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, meteor

When i click into a field within a form and press enter, the form is submitted.

This is not good for my usecase and it needs to be avoided.

i tried several steps without success:

**template.rendered**

```
$('#myForm').on("keyup keypress", function(e) {
    var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
    if (code  == 13) {
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
});

$("form").submit(function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

**Template.events**

```
"keyup #myform": function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
}
```

Nothing helped yet. I am using Meteor and semantic-ui.

What else could help?

Comment: Removing the form-tag would prevent every submit but i'll give it a try

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work for me because i use the form tag for validation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change this:

```
"keyup #myform": function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
}
```

to:

```
"submit #myform": function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
}
```

Clicking "enter" triggers "submit", so you are wasting your time trying to figure out which keycode associates to "enter".

Comment: i use the "submit #myform" event for submitting the form which is good. I just want that pressing the enter key does not trigger the submit!

Comment: Then use "click" instead of "submit"?

Comment: Unfortunately the semantic-UI framework still does validation on every submit / enter which will trigger the GUI marking every field invalid on pressing enter. Anyway changing to "click" does not trigger the whole actions now. Thanks for this hint ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Template.<your_template_name>.events({        
   // Submit form event
    'submit form': function(event){
        // Stop form submission
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Comment: It would just block every form submit. There is no easy way (to my little knowledge) to check if it comes from a user pressing "enter" or if it is the submit button pressed.

Comment: I assumed he has a button or something like "Post" that triggers the actual submit.

Comment: Ok, you're right. My bad, it could be more elegant than blocking "enter" on every field.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you use a `keydown` event if you want to prevent the form from being submitted only when the user press "enter" within a form field?

That way, you could even allow it only for the last field of your form.